# PHP Usando SESSION com Array

Tags: php, array, session, get, foreach

Boa noite pessoal, o meu objetivo é quando voltar para a página produtos, e voltar para o carrinho, mantendo a variável de sessão e também preencher a página carrinho com mais produtos cada vez que o array recebe um novo, pois está gerando um produto só. Desde já agradeço. Segue o código abaixo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->

   <?php session_start();?>

   <html>
   <head lang="pt-br">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>E-Commerce</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <h1>Produtos</h1>



    <ul>
        <li><a href="ipad.php">Ipad</a></li>
        <li><a href="playstation.php">Playstation</a></li>
        <li><a href="xbox.php">Xbox</a></li>
    </ul>

    <br/>

    <a href="carrinho.php">Ver Carrinho</a>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Agora a página carrinho.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
    <?php session_start(); ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>E-Commerce</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Carrinho de Compras</h1>

    <?php

    $_SESSION['valor'] = array();

    array_push($_SESSION['valor'], $_GET['valor']);

    ?>

    <?php foreach($_SESSION['valor'] as $list):?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $list;?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <a href="produtos.php">Continuar Comprando</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="#">Efetuar Pagamentos</a>




    </body>
    </html>
```

E a página produto, que difere das outras só no nome produto passado pela url,

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->

    <?php session_start();?>

    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>E-Commerce</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>IPAD</h1>

    <ul>

        <li><a href="carrinho.php?valor=ipad">Colocar no Carrinho</li>
        <li><a href="carrinho.php">Ver Carrinho</a></li>
        <li><a href="produtos.php">Produtos</a></li>
    </ul>


    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

O que não estou conseguindo é quando sair e voltar pro carrinho continuar visualizando o produto, e apresentar mais produtos na página carrinho. Desde já valeu !

Answer (score 2):

### [Clique para testar](http://runnable.com/VQDn8dSP_1Qx5qsM/output)

**Código:**

```
<?php 

//iniciando a asessão
session_start ();
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",true);

?>


<html> 
<head> 
    <title> Demonstração de matriz Session usado para carrinho</title> 
</head> 
<body>
    <?php 

    //Calculando o total com a função sizeof() que retorna de key's.

    if (!isset($_GET['carrinho']) && isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])) {

        $contagem = sizeof($_SESSION['carrinho']);

    }

    if (isset($_GET['carrinho'])) {

        $contagem = sizeof($_SESSION['carrinho']) + 1;

    }

    echo "Número de itens no carrinho =" .$contagem."<a href=index.php?vazio=0><br />Remover tudo </a> <br> ";?> 

    <br /><br /><br />
    <a href="index.php?carrinho=1">Calça Brega</a><br />
    <a href="index.php?carrinho=2">Pirulito pop</a><br />
    <a href="index.php?carrinho=3">Carro de luxo</a><br />

</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['carrinho'])){    

    $prod_id = $_GET['carrinho'];

    //isto evita o uso da função array push
    $_SESSION['carrinho'][] = $prod_id;


 } 

//removendo todos os produtos
if (isset($_GET['vazio'])) {

    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_SESSION['carrinho'])) { 
        //echo "$key -> $val <br>"; 
        unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$key]);
        $contagem = 0;

    }

}




if (isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])) {
echo '<br /><br />ID dos poutos adicionados:';
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $list):?>

    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $list;?></li>
    </ul>

<?php endforeach; } 

//fim :)
```

Comment: Então isso já fiz, mas, o meu código continua dando o problema de: Notice: Undefined index: valor in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto_PHPSessions\carrinho.php on line 11 // Quando volto pro Carrinho e não está somando mais de um produto.

Comment: Onde fica a linha 11??? Acho que já sei.

Comment: array_push($_SESSION['carrinho'], $_GET['valor']); // É está a linha.

Comment: Então passei o valor $_GET['valor'] para $variavel e não é assim também rsr Tem um jeito de obter por $_GET ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21874/discussion-between-lollipop-and-thiago).

Comment: Ainda não entendi, ficou confuso, o isset add aqui, resolveu aquele problema, agora, de sair da página e manter o valor não.

Comment: o valor é mantido no $_SESSION['carrinho']

Comment: Você tem que iniciar o session_start ();, antes

Comment: @Thiago, nada ainda?